# Column comparison SQL issue in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query and needs to get the mismatch column records in MS Access.

The issue is when there are more than one records with same link column value, matching is not happening properly

Query

```
SELECT 
    T1Col1,
    T1Col2,
    T2Col1,
    T2Col2
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 
    ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
WHERE T1.Col2 <> T2.Col2
```

After executing I am getting below kind of results which is not correct

```
T1Col1  T1Col2 T2Col1  T2Col2

abc     ccc    abc     eee
abc     eee    abc     ccc
```

Ideally above records should not return in the result set as those matches (checking for not matching ones). Do I need to change anything in the query to get the correct results

T1

```
T1Col1  T1Col2 

jkl     ttt
efg     qqq
efg     mmm
abc     ccc    
abc     eee
```

T2

```
T2Col1  T2Col2

jkl    sss
efg    uuu
efg    mmm
abc    eee
abc    ccc
```

Expected results would be

```
T1Col1  T1Col2 T2Col1  T2Col2

jkl     ttt    jkl     sss
efg     qqq    efg     uuu
```

Comment: how is it not correct? t1.col2 and t2.col2 are not equal in either of your sample result rows, which is exactly what you put into the SQL statement.

Comment: Thax for your update Marc. What I meant was as edited my initial post, If you check the T1 and T2 data seperately. Those results records should match, which is picking up in the query out put as mismatch

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't make any sense.  Now you have two results sets - you can't get two results from one query.  What are you trying to do?  What does "mismatch column records" mean?  Can you give a larger example of your data in the two original tables, maybe 15-20 rows in each table, and then an example of the single table you'd like returned?

Comment: ... break it up into two queries and only SELECT the two columns you need?

Comment: Please have a look on added sample data with expected results

Comment: I think I understand, though your sample expected results seem just slightly off - why is 'efg qqq efg mmm' a valid response, since 'efg mmm' is in both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is the most efficient solution, but it'll work.

The problem with a simple join is that you are performing a cartesian join of ALL records in T1 with ALL records in T2, then deleting the ones that fail your criteria.  Thus, you get results you're not asking for, because you're not doing the query that matches your english (or native-language-of-your-choice).  SQL is great that way - most of the time, if you just say out loud what you want, exactly, the SQL matches.

What you want:

> Select those rows from T1 where there is no row in T2 with the same
>   value for COL1 and COL2.  Then select those rows from T2 where there
>   is no row in T1 with the same value for COL1 and COL2.  Then match
>   these two result sets up to each other by COL1.

So, here you go:

```
create table t3 as 
  select * from 
    (select * from t1 where not exists (select 1 from T2 where T1col1=t2col1 and t1col2=t2col2)) M1,
    (select * from t2 where not exists (select 1 from T1 where T1col1=t2col1 and t1col2=t2col2)) M2
    where M1.t1col1=M2.t2col1;
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Here Col1 is the joining key in both table. Col2 is the the column that we should find for mismatches.